# different Models in MVVM

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, architecture, mvvm, model

I am working with Linq to sql wich provide me some basic class like **Car**. So that I get a list of cars as *IQueryable*.

These cars are then processed by my business Logic to become **CarProcessed** with two added property so that I have an *IList*.

This IList is called by my silverlight application and  I am to use this list in a grid,  and do things with this information in order to change the color of the line according to the type of the car. Therefore I will get **CarModel** with a color property that  I will be able to bind to my view directly.

Is it a normal process? That means I am not working with a single Model but Three. One for the Data, one for the Business Logic, and a last one for the presentation layer.

Do you think it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends. If you're having some complex transformations between models then they can affect performance. Otherwise, what you're doing is a common practice given that different devices and by the way interfaces require different presentations models, also the business logic manages entities with certain properties not UI nor Data must know about it and finally your data requires some specific transformation to persist and load that maybe require some other ones.

However try to see for common patterns like [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to see if no other one suits your needs.

Also, remember that multi-model presentation if one the advantages of MVVM.

Comment: thanks, that mvvm pattern was giving me serious doubt about whether I was doing things right or not...

Comment: @Arthis do you have plans of make different UIs (maybe for different devices?)

Comment: yes. I have Silverlight application and a Mail input/output application

Comment: You can create a new project (Entities) and share them (as usually do with cross cutting concerns logic), just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

If the color property is only used for presentation purposes you don't usually make it part of the model, but define a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) for the Control you are displaying CarProcessed objects with.

In this DataTemplate, or in the DataTemplates Style, you define a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.aspx) that checks for a specific condition of your CarProcessed and sets the color accordingly.

Here is the part of a WPF tutorial that deals with DataTemplates: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_4.aspx